# switch view iphone - switching to empty view

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

i got a 3 view controller - Register, Login, Profile
and i got a UISegmentedControl that i can switch views by from Register to main and from Login to main too. 
but when i'm in Register view for Example id like to switch users to profile view after finishing registration.

[image]

[image]

and here's the Code..

```
-(IBAction) switchView :(id)sender{

switch (segControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
    {
        HangmanViewController * main =[[HangmanViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        main.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentModalViewController:main animated:YES];
        [main release];
    }
        break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:
    {
        Profile *profile2 = [[Profile alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:profile2 animated:YES];
        [profile2 release];

    }break;


    default:
        break;
}
```

}

and i Already imported the .h file of Profile Class.. 
so what's wrong !!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand you question perfectly hope this will help you.

```
       - (IBAction)SegmentControll:(id)sender {

                 if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {

                      //your main view  

                   }

                 if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {

                      //your Profile view  

                   }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to switch users to profile view  only after  Successfully finishing registration/login otherwise show alert ?

then you may try this :

in your .h file

```
NSString *count;
```

in your .m file

```
 @Synthesize count;
```

in your ViewdidLoad

```
count=@"1";
```

//so here default value of count is 1

// after Successfully finishing registration/login  make count =2

```
 count=@"2";
```

In your SegmentControl Action make this condition :

```
- (IBAction)SegmentControll:(id)sender 

           {

             if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==0) 

                   {

                 if (count isEqualToString:@"2") {
                 //your main view 
                     }
              else
                 // alert for login/Register
                }

             if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {

                  //your Profile view  

               }

      if (SegmentControll.selectedSegmentIndex==2) {

                  //your Register view  

               }
     }
```